# What can cause new PDO to be NULL

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Good evening guys I'm a new comer to OOP and I've been having some problem.
after I call

```
private function __construct(){
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=' . config::get('mysql/host'),
        'dbname=' . config::get('mysql/db'),
        config::get('mysql/username'), 
        config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

then I call

```
$this->_pdo->prepare($sql)
```

and it said Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

So I var_dump($this->_pdo) and the result is NULL. What can be causing this problem?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Where do you call it, inside the constructor or somewhere else?

Comment: Your 'dsn' string is incorrect. The PDO constructor takes three parameters with an 'optional' array of options. see the first example: [pdo.construct.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php). the 'dsn' should be something like: mysql:host=' . config::get('mysql/host'). ';dbname=' . config::get('mysql/db'). i.e. one string. To clarify, the 'username' is the second parameter and the password is the third.

Answer (score 1):

Juan saw it, but didn't explain -- you are missing a semicolon after the hostname and before dbname.

You'd be better served by splitting up that blob of code and building the credentials string as a separate step, then you could have var_dumped it too and seen the problem straight off:

```
$host = config::get('mysql/host');
$db = config::get('mysql/db');
$creds = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db"
$this->_pdo = new PDO(
    $creds,
    config::get('mysql/username'),
    config::get('mysql/password')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php    
    private function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.config::get('mysql/db'),config::get('mysql/username'),config::get('mysql/password'));
        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
?>
```